# Bluemix Workflow Service - Plugin Handshake Timeout

Tags: workflow, ibm-cloud

As part of the setup to use the Workflow Service in Bluemix, a plugin is required, added to your DevOps project associated with Workflow.  The "install plugin" pre-populates the Orion install plugin field with:

```
https://workflow.ng.bluemix.net/workflow/devOpsServices/workflowPlugin.html
```

After a minute or so, this consistently times out with:

```
Plugin handshake timeout for: http://workflow.ng.bluemix.net/workflow/devOpsServices/workflowPlugin.html
```

As you can see, the timeout is on an `http://` url rather than `https://` , this being consequential or relevant, I'm unsure.

I did also try a straight `http://` url instead with the same effect.  Also, different computer, same steps, same result.

Any additional troubleshooting come to mind?

TIA

Comment: The Bluemix Workflow Service team is aware of your question and is working on an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we tried to reproduce the issue but it seems as the issue is gone and the whole installation worked for us in Google Chrome. Do you still encounter the issue? Please retry. What you're describing seems like an endless loop redirecting http to https. If you still encounter the problem, please let us know, and we'll continue with our investigations. Regards, R.

Comment: It seems to have cleared up as I tried recently and I can confirm the error is now gone.